# Can one combine depression and self discipline?

Tags: research, depression

Depressed persons typically stop performing basic tasks such as eating regularly, taking showers, going out and other similar mundane and boring tasks that requires self some discipline.

My questions is: can someone who is very disciplined and goes up 7 o'clock every morning, have breakfast, take a shower, brush her teeth, go out to meet people and perform errands like everyone else (assume this person is on sick leave for depression and doesn't need to do all these chores but could instead sleep all day and watch TV all night) etc - still suffer from, and be diagnosed with, depression?

Comment: This is really going to be person dependent. What one person could achieve, another might not be able to. Some will say yes, some will say no, there is no real definitive answer for this. I would suggest that if this is something you or someone you know is struggling with, that you consult with a mental health professional.

Comment: @JohnP What? The question is not "can EVERYONE combine A and B", it is "can ANYONE combine A and B" where A and B are somewhat contradictory. The question is fine. Cf: Q: "can you be both right- and lefthanded?" A: "Yes it is called being 'ambidextrous'". Q: Can you be both depressed and disciplined? A: Yes, it is called atypical depression. Approximately 5 % of all patients diagnosed with depression behave like that (source: XX). Or something like that. Stop being trigger happy.

Comment: The comment about atypical depression is fairly accurate EXCEPT "atypical" depression is actually more common than "typical" depression.  But it actually sounds like OP is doubting that someone who claims to have depression (and is on sick leave for it) really has it, given that the individual appears to still be successfully accomplishing many activities of daily living.  Depression is complicated, pervasive, and often people suffer profoundly from it while managing to keep it well hidden.  You cannot exclude the diagnosis of depression (or anxiety etc) based on how someone appears to act.

Comment: @DoctorWhom It is actually the other way around. Someone I think should be diagnosed with depression is denied that because she is so disciplined and I am looking for sources to support her case.

Comment: @hensti - I edited your question fairly heavily in the second half. Originally it was very slanted and geared towards one person, which is off topic. I edited to make it more general, yet still give you information towards what you are looking for. Please let me know if this is acceptable.

Comment: @JohnP Your editing didn't add anything to the question.

Comment: @hensti He saved your question from almost certain closure. You might want to read the [help] and learn how this exchange works. Requests for personal medical advice are strictly off topic, and that's what your question was.

Comment: No it wasn't. I asked if two "contradictive" indications could exist simultaneously.

Comment: @hensti Yes it is. I have downvoted and voted-to-close this post because in this form, it is asking about a special case. If you ask about contradicting indications, just leave JohnP‘s edit, which is exaclty about that.

Comment: Voting to close because this question has been reverted to a personal question.

Comment: @BryanKrause Define "personal question". I am not holding my breath.

Comment: @hentsi "Questions requesting personal medical advice are off-topic here. Nobody here can properly address your health issues. Such questions should be taken to your personal physician who can examine you and access your full medical records. For more information, please see [this meta post](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/are-personal-medical-advice-questions-on-topic-here)."

Comment: To further summarize, we blanket avoid answering questions about specific individuals because answering some of those questions can be dangerous, and it is far better to simply reject all health questions about an individual rather than argue whether each and every example represents a possible danger, in part because the community should not be trusted to determine those dangers.

Comment: I suggest you read the original version of my question again and quote wherever I suggest a personal connection there. However, it is quite obvious that most questions, both here on Health or any other SE-site will be triggered by some personal experience. I wouldn't have thought about this matter unless I had a friend in such a situation. That does not make it personal in any meaningful sense of the word.

Answer (score 1):

> Depressed persons typically stop performing basic tasks such as eating regularly, taking showers, going out and other similar mundane and boring tasks that requires self some discipline.

[citation needed]

> What I am looking for is documentation or case studies on people that have been diagnosed with depression, yet still manage to perform normal ADL (Activities of daily living) such as grocery shopping, errands, social activities. How prevalent is the stereotypical lay in bed type of depression versus functional depression, and where can I find more resources on this?

[There are cases of depression with ADL, and they are at least as common as the major depressive disorder](https://www.webmd.com/depression/features/cope-depression).

---

Depression is a highly individual disease and comes in many sizes, shapes and forms. A form of depression is [dysthymia](https://web.archive.org/web/20100106064958/http://www.health.harvard.edu/newsweek/Dysthymia.htm), or persistent depressive disorder (PDD) a long-lasting (>2 years) depression during which the individual may be functioning, and may also suffer from episodes of major depressive disorders (known as double-depression). This does not mean that PDD is less severe than other types of depression like MDD (major depressive disorder) or post-natal depression.

The major depressive disorder (MDD) as such is defined as *[a combination of symptoms that interfere with the ability to work, study, sleep, eat, and enjoy once pleasurable activities. Such a disabling episode of depression may occur only once but more commonly occurs several times in a lifetime.](http://http:)* This means that there is a form of depression which is defined by being „disabling“ in a way. This does not mean that all types (or even more than one specific type of depression)